# Get all properties of Browsable attribute

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, system.reflection

I have a class which have many properties and some properties have `Browsable` attribute.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string City;

    public int prpId
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public string prpName
    {
        get { return Name; }
        set { Name = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public string prpCity
    {
        get { return City; }
        set { City= value; }
    }
}
```

Now using `Reflection`, how can I filter the properties which have `Browsable attributes`? In this case I need to get `prpName` and `prpCity` only.

Here is the code I have tried so far.

```
 List<PropertyInfo> pInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().ToList();
```

but this selects all the properties. Is there any way to filter properties which have `Browsable attributes` only?

Comment: you want all properties that has Browsable, right? or just the ones with Browsable(true) ?

Comment: All properties with browsable @Selman22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Attribute.IsDefined`](http://Attribute.IsDefined) method to check if `Browsable` attribute is defined in property:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()
               .Where(pi => Attribute.IsDefined(pi, typeof(BrowsableAttribute)))
               .ToList();
```

Comment: That will also include `[Browsable(false)]`.

Answer (score 4):

To include only members having `[Browsable(true)]`, you can use:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()
               .Where(pi => pi.GetCustomAttributes<BrowsableAttribute>().Contains(BrowsableAttribute.Yes))
               .ToList();
```

Comment: How to get the value of the column which marked as Browsable to false.